# error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (...) not found

Tags: android, xml, flutter, build.gradle

I get the following error while trying to run my flutter_app.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     D:\azzam\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:57: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.soerjdev.flutter_app:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

And This is my file in D:\azzam\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:57:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.soerjdev.flutter_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <!--
         Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:label="Enakabe" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.soerjdev.flutter_app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!--
                 Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity                              //This is line 57
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <provider
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.soerjdev.flutter_app.flutter.image_provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/flutter_image_picker_file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I am really stuck please help me.

I have tried several attempts to solve this, but does not work.